# How to use lib classes in controller

Tags: magento2.2.3, 3rd-party-library

I have a controller `Callback.php` in folder `app/code/Dots/Socialfeeds/Controller/Social` in custom module  `Dots_Socialfeeds`.

I am also using an third party library file `Linkedin.php` which I have placed in folder `lib/external/Dots/Socialfeeds/Linkedin`.

Now I want to use this lib class in my above controller `Callback.php`.

**code**--

```
<?php

namespace Dots\Socialfeeds\Controller\Social;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Dots\Socialfeeds\Linkedin\Linkedin;

/**
 * Class Callback
 *
 * @package Dots\Socialfeeds\Controller\Social
 */
class Callback extends Action
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {       
        $li =   new \Linkedin(
                      array(
                        'api_key' => '81a592y6mz9o33', 
                        'api_secret' => 'kviv5GtPAt3ZDHpq', 
                        'callback_url' => 'http://ds01.projectstatus.co.uk/c2cwp/test.php?type=linkedin'
                      )
                    );
       $token = $li->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    }


}
```

**and lib file code** --

```
    <?php
namespace Dots\Socialfeeds\Linkedin;

class Linkedin
{
private $_config = array();
private $_state = null;
private $_access_token = null;
private $_access_token_expires = null;
private $_debug_info = null;
private $_curl_handle = null;

const API_BASE = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1';
const OAUTH_BASE = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2';

const SCOPE_BASIC_PROFILE = 'r_basicprofile'; // Name, photo, headline, and current positions
const SCOPE_FULL_PROFILE = 'r_fullprofile'; // Full profile including experience, education, skills, and recommendations
const SCOPE_EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'r_emailaddress'; // The primary email address you use for your LinkedIn account
const SCOPE_NETWORK = 'r_network'; // Your 1st and 2nd degree connections
const SCOPE_CONTACT_INFO = 'r_contactinfo'; // Address, phone number, and bound accounts
const SCOPE_READ_WRITE_UPDATES = 'rw_nus'; // Retrieve and post updates to LinkedIn as you
const SCOPE_READ_WRITE_GROUPS = 'rw_groups'; // Retrieve and post group discussions as you
const SCOPE_READ_WRITE_COMPANY_ADMIN = 'rw_company_admin'; // Administers a company as you
const SCOPE_WRITE_MESSAGES = 'w_messages'; // Send messages and invitations to connect as you
const SCOPE_WRITE_SHARE = 'w_share'; // Share url to your contacts

const HTTP_METHOD_GET = 'GET';
const HTTP_METHOD_POST = 'POST';
const HTTP_METHOD_PUT = 'PUT';
const HTTP_METHOD_DELETE = 'DELETE';

/**
 * @param array $config (api_key, api_secret, callback_url)
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public function __construct(array $config)
{
    if (!isset($config['api_key']) || empty($config['api_key'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid api key - make sure api_key is defined in the config array');
    }

    if (!isset($config['api_secret']) || empty($config['api_secret'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid api secret - make sure api_secret is defined in the config array');
    }

    if (!isset($config['callback_url']) || empty($config['callback_url'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid callback url - make sure callback_url is defined in the config array');
    }

    if (!extension_loaded('curl')) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('PHP CURL extension does not seem to be loaded');
    }

    $this->_config = $config;
}

 .....
 .....
```

I am getting error if in controller file-

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Linkedin' not found in app/code/Dots/Socialfeeds/Controller/Social/Callback.php:24

Comment: Did you check my comment?

Answer (score 1):

In your module put this in **registration.php**

```
require_once(BP.'/lib/external/Dots/Socialfeeds/Linkedin.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in your controller :

```
require_once(BP.'/lib/external/Dots/Socialfeeds/Linkedin.php')
```

Comment: I think it should be require_once() not required_once. I have used it still now working. I think use of require _once function in controller is not a standard way to implement.

Comment: I have used this but still getting same error

Comment: Yes. U r right. It's require. I will change it.

Comment: You can add it by xml file also. For that, You need to create lib/web/Socialfeeds/Linkedin.php folder like this.

Comment: Like : <item type="file">Lib::Socialfeeds/Linkedin.php</item>

Comment: I don't now how to do that @Rohan

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject this class `Dots/Socialfeeds/Linkedin` _construct function of `Dots\Socialfeeds\Controller\Social\Callback`.

```
class Callback extends Action
{
  protected $linkedin;     
  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Dots\Socialfeeds\Linkedin $Linkedin
    ) {
        $this->linkedin = $Linkedin(
                      array(
                        'api_key' => '81a592y6mz9o33', 
                        'api_secret' => 'kviv5GtPAt3ZDHpq', 
                        'callback_url' => 'http://ds01.projectstatus.co.uk/c2cwp/test.php?type=linkedin'
                      )
                    );       
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
        $li =   $this->linkedin;
       $token = $li->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it and getting this error--
{"0":"Missing required argument $config of Dots\\Socialfeeds\\Linkedin\\Linkedin.","1":"#0 \/home\/c2cmage\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(34): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Dots\\\\Socialfeed...', Array, Array)\n#1 \/home\/c2cmage\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php(59):

Comment: I have updated linkedin.php , kindly check above code